# Area of hyperbolic triangle definition

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry

I found this question recently in my booklet on hyperbolic geometry asking a very simple question but I could not answer it:

> Why can we not define the area of a hyperbolic triangle as in the plane as half the product of the perpendicular and the base?

I know the half plane model and the Poincare disk models but I cannot find a satisfactory explanation. I thought it might have something to do with that there are no rectangles in hyperbolic geometry but I cannot proceed. Help appreciated.

Comment: I began to studied hyperbolic geometry three weeks ago, so I am not sure for the exact reason. But as far as I known, if we defined the area in hyperbolic plane as we did in Euclid plane, then at least the möbius transformations would not preserve the area as we except. I am really new at this topic, so I am not sure for my commenting.

Comment: Nice question, but above my knowledge, i made a relatd question of a (tiny) bit simpler problem see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462778/area-of-a-right-angled-hyperbolic-triangle-as-function-of-side-lengths

Comment: Well, one reason is that in hyperbolic geometry $ah_a\neq bh_b$, so this 'area' would depend on the side we choose as the base — so in a sense it's not well-defined.

Comment: @KWSK Well, (hyperbolic) lengths of both the base and the (hyperbolic) perpedicular _are_ manifestly invariant under hyperbolic motions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the area? Well, at least we want it to be (1) a non-negative function of a polygon that is (2) *additive*: $S(A\cup B)=S(A)+S(B)$ if $A\cap B$ has no interior points. It turns out, these two simple properties define $S$ almost uniquely — it's unique up to multiplication by a constant.

Now in Euclidean geometry one can prove that $S(\Delta)=ah_a$ by considering a triangle inside the rectangle — but because 'there are no hyperbolic rectangle' the same proof doesn't work in hyperbolic geometry.

[image: triangle inside rectangle]

Comment: Thank you for a very clear well written answer

Comment: When scale factor for length  is non-linear and varies point to point in either of these models what meaning can be there for an area, using a euclidean yardstick ?